# Session is not working in Magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, session

I am currently working on a magneto project. I make one color picker for demo purpose so that user can change the color on that demo site. What i doing basically in this i get the color code and then make an ajax call which store the values in session. This working great in simple php. I don't have any idea how its work in Magneto. Here is my All code

> My Ajax code

```
function colorbg(){
            var colorbg = jQuery( "#colorbgi" ).val();

            //alert( colorbg );
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/ajax_set_color.php'); ?>",
              data: { colorbg: colorbg }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
                  alert( msg +" color code" );
                  jQuery(".menu_container").css("background-color", '#'+msg);

              });

    }
```

HTML code

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Background Color: &nbsp;</td>
            <td><input class="color" value="66ff00" name="colorbg" id="colorbgi" onChange="colorbg()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Ajax file where i am trying to store session

```
<?php
    $inputMessage = $_REQUEST['colorbg'];
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setWelcomeMessage($inputMessage);
    print $_REQUEST['colorbg'];
```

The code where i am getting the session values

```
<?php
    $outputMessage = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getWelcomeMessage();
    echo $this->__($outputMessage);
?>
```

So any suggestion where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Session start in magento  is done in controller pre-dispatch action. if you are using custom file, you need to initialise it manually .

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax file, at the top add this:

```
require("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
```

This will initialize Magento so you'll be able to access those Magento session variables.